# Probability about a deck of cards

Tags: probability, card-games

"What is the probability of drawing either an ace or a diamond in a single draw from a fair deck of cards?" For this question would I need to subtract the ace of diamonds in my calculation because it is both a diamond and an ace and I would not want to calculate this twice. Here is what I did:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\text{ ace or diamond }) &= \frac{\# \text{ ace or diamond} }{\# \text{ total}}\\
& = \frac{4 + 13 - 1}{52} \\
&\approx 0.30769
\end{align}$$

$-1$ was done to remove common repeated card "ace of diamond".

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: That's correct. You used the following formula: $\vert A\cup B\vert=\vert A\vert+\vert B\vert-\vert A\cap B\vert$ where $\vert\cdot\vert$ denotes the number of elements in a particular set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already received the answer you expected in comments, but here is a detailed answer of why it is the good way to compute this probability.

Suppose that you have a finite set $\Omega$ (here, $\Omega$ is the set of all $52$ cards in your deck). You consider here that the events are $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, i.e. the so-called **power set** of $\Omega$. The power set of $\Omega$ is defined as the set of all subsets of $\Omega$. For example, $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ contains the set $\{\text{Ace diamond },\text{ Jack club },\text{ 7 club },\text{ 8 heart }\}$.

Actually, $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ contains all the "events" on $\Omega$. For example, the event "ace or diamond" is 
$$\begin{align}
&\{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are aces or diamonds}\}\\
&=\{\text{ Ace diamond },\text{ Ace heart }, \text{ Ace club },\text{ Ace spade }, \color{red}{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,\text{ jack }, \text{ queen },\text{ king } \text{ diamonds }}\}
\end{align}$$
which is clearly a subset of $\Omega$, so that it belongs to $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.

Equiprobability implies that the probability that an event $A\in\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ occurs is equal to the number of elements in $A$ divided by the number of elements in $\Omega$. We shall denote $\vert A\vert$ the number of elements in a set $A$. We shall denote $A\cup B$ the union of $A$ and $B$, which is the set of the elements that are in $A$ or in $B$ or in both, while $A\cap B$ denotes the intersection of $A$ and $B$, which is the set of elements that are in $A$ AND in $B$.

A famous formula (known as the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)) is the following:

$$\vert A\cup B\vert = \vert A\vert + \vert B\vert - \vert A\cap B\vert\tag{1}$$

which can be read "The number of elements that are in $A$ or in $B$ or in both is equal to the number of elements in $A$ plus the number of elements in $B$, minus the elements in $A$ and $B$". Why is that intuitively true? Because if there are elements in $A$ and in $B$, when we make $\vert A\vert +\vert B\vert$, we double count the elements that are both in $A$ and $B$, so that we have to take out one time these elements, which are by definition $A\cap B$.

Let's write $A=\{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are aces or diamonds}\}$. Now, you have (**because of equiprobability**, which is the main argument here):

$$
\mathbb{P}[A] = \frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}
$$

Here, $\vert \Omega\vert = 52$. But what is $\vert A\vert$ in your case? We can rewrite:

$$\begin{align}
&\{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are aces or diamonds}\}\\
&=\{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are aces}\}\,\cup\,\{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are diamonds}\} \\
\end{align}$$

So, if we use formula $(1)$ to compute $\vert A\vert$:

$$\begin{align}
\vert A\vert &=\left\vert\{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are aces or diamonds}\}\right\vert\\
&=\left\vert \{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are aces}\}\,\cup\,\{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are diamonds}\}\right\vert\\
&=\color{blue}{\left\vert \{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are aces}\}\right\vert}+\color{green}{\left\vert\{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are diamonds}\}\right\vert} -\color{red}{\left\vert\{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are aces AND diamonds}\}\right\vert}\\
&= \color{blue}{4} + \color{green}{13} - \color{red}{1}
\end{align}$$
so that
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[A] &= \mathbb{P}\left[\{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are aces or diamonds}\}\right]\\
&=\frac{\left\vert\{\text{Cards }\in\Omega\mid \text{Cards are aces or diamonds}\}\right\vert}{\vert\Omega\vert}\\
&=\frac{4+13-1}{52}\\
&=\frac{4}{13}\\
&\approx 0.30769
\end{align}$$